# How to access the Web Methods of webservice in the dll without any app.config?

Tags: c#, web-services, dll, windows

- I have one dll which uses webservice reference of one webservice.
- For that i have to add the < client > in the < system.serviceModel > of app.config of that dll.
- I have give reference of that dll in other project.
- When i am tried to run the application it gives me an exception **"Could not find default endpoint element."**
- I searched the solution regarding this issue and get to know that i have to add  in the  in the app.config of the project in which i have referred the dll.
- **So is there any way to initialize the webservice client without modifying the app.config of project in which we have reference of that dll?**

Answer (score 0):

where from you want read binding configs? if you want to set hardcoded , you can use this constructure of your proxy class..

```
public YourServiceSoapClient(System.ServiceModel.Channels.Binding binding, System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress remoteAddress) : 
            base(binding, remoteAddress) {
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this issue by directly downloading the WSDL class file of that web service.

I have facing another issue regarding the web service.

I have to add the System.Web.Services reference in the dll as well as the parent project in which i am including the dll.

So is there any way to use the WSDL class of web service without adding the reference System.Web.Services.